# How to get value of HTML span tag while running on php webdriver client and selenium

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, selenium

I am using `php` `webdriver` client and`selnium`

I am frustrated in getting value from span tag Rs 350

```
<div class="fareBlock busDataBlock">
                <div>
                <span class="fareStart"></span>
                <span class="fareSpan">
                    Rs
                    <span class="Fare">350</span>
                </span>
                    </div>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="SpecialBus"></a>
                <button class="viewSeatsBtn">View Seats</button>
            </div>
```

I want to get value 350 to print on my HTML Page. I want to use a `for` loop for this because many span tags with different values are there .

I want the values of span tags and to be displayed on my webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below xpath with java to get the value 350:

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='fareBlock busDataBlock']/div/span[2]/span"));
```

Below statement is implemented in php:

```
driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath("//div[@class='fareBlock busDataBlock']/div/span[2]/span"))
```